# Teamcity, set configuration parameter for next build

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to set/change a build parameter from build 1 to be used in build 2.

In build 1 I have a build step that sets a configuration parameter like this:

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='ENVIRONMENT' value='%Target environment%']"
```

And in a build step on build 2, I want to use this environment variable in a rake task by
specifying `%ENVIRONMENT%`

The problem I have is that the configuration parameter is not visible in build 2. I have surely missed something essential.

I have also tried with env variables but that seems like the wrong approach as this is just configuration variables which is not needed in a build script.

Any clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can publish an artifact with the value you want in build 1, introduce an artifact dependency from build 2 to build 1, and in the first step of build 2 transform that artifact into a configuration value again for the other steps in build 2 by using the echo (or better `Write-Host`) statement you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this in the same way I did for:
[Is it possible to permanently update the value of a TeamCity build parameter as a result of a custom run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339074/is-it-possible-to-permanently-update-the-value-of-a-teamcity-build-parameter-as)

Build 1 can update a variable which is being used in build 2 rather than build 2 trying to read a parameter in build 1.

Download and install [CURL](http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin) on build agent:

Add a command line step to build 1:

```
curl -v --request PUT -d "%Target environment%" --Header "Content-Type: text/plain" http://username:password@servername:8080/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/Build2Project/parameters/ENVIRONMENT
```

This updates the value of a parameter on a project, but you can use the REST API to update it on a particular build configuration if you prefer.

All REST.API documentation for TeamCity v8 can be found [on their website](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API)

Answer (score 1):

You can reference `MyVariable` variable which you set in Build configuration 1 in a script in Build configuration X such way: `%dep.BuildConfiguration1Id.MyVariable%`

Comment: This worked for me, although it seems that you also need to specify at least one artifact, when setting up the dependency, even if you don't need any.