# How do i set a parameter in one step that i can use in another

Tags: teamcity

I would like to set a variable of some description in one step of by build configuration that I can use in another step.

So in step 1 I set the variable and in step 2 i read the variable

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it **within the same build configuration** you would need to use [service messages](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-CommonProperties)

To share **between build configurations** within the same project you can do it via Project parameters. Currently as of TeamCity 8.1, to set it in the build you would need to add a step to run [curl.exe](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) utility and set parameter value via TeamCity [REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API).

```
C:\Path\To\curl.exe -v --request PUT -d "YourParamValue" --Header "Content-Type: text/plain" http://YourUser:YourPassword@YourTeamcity.server.local:port/httpAuth/app/rest/projects/YourProjectName/parameters/YourParameter
```

Related: [Teamcity, set configuration parameter for next build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495661/teamcity-set-configuration-parameter-for-next-build/)

[TeamCity, passing an id generated in one build step to a later build step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219493/teamcity-passing-an-id-generated-in-one-build-step-to-a-later-build-step?rq=1)

Comment: Yeah, service messages are what I was looking for. "##teamcity[setParameter name='foo' value='bar']" did the trick.