# Updating project-level parameter in build step in TeamCity 10

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-10

I am currently implementing (I do not know if implementing is the appropriate word, but anyway) a semantic versioning in TeamCity. I have project level system parameters in which I store version number parts: `system.major`, `system.minor`, and `system.patch`. I have two build configurations:

- First, we call it **beta**, is using the *major*, *minor*, and *patch* as-is and appends its build counter value to the version (i.e 1.0.0.X where X is beta's build count).
- Second, we call it **release**, is using the *major*, and *minor* (but not *patch*) as-is and appends its build counter value as patch number (i.e 1.0.Y where Y is release's build count).

We want our versions to increment like following:

1. A *beta* build is run: 1.0.0.**1**
2. Another *beta* build: 1.0.0.**2**
3. A *release* build is run: 1.0.**1**.0
4. Yet another *beta* build: 1.0.1.**3**

The problem is, we want to use the *release* build's counter as patch number in *beta* build as well, without any human intervention. So far, I have read about people using assembly info or external VCS-tracked file to store the current version in last build step and parse the file in the first build step of every build configuration. This approach, though appears to be the standard way, is not welcomed by the project's manager, so I want to avoid using assembly info or another VCS-tracked file to store the version info. I have tried to use a powershell script build step in *release* configuration to set the parameter *patch* using:

```
Write-Host "##teamcity[setParameter name='system.patch' value='%build.counter%']"
```

yet, using `teamcity[setParameter...]` appears to take effect inside the running build and only on consecutive build steps. What I want is to set the system parameters in one build (release) and later, use their value in another build configuration (beta).

Is there any straight-forward way that I fail to see? If you have similar experience, can you point me to the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to permanently update the value of a TeamCity build parameter as a result of a custom run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339074/is-it-possible-to-permanently-update-the-value-of-a-teamcity-build-parameter-as)

Comment: I'm flagging this question as it seems to be a duplicate of [psych's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23339074/3136110). Sorry, I could not have realized this before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am accomplishing something similar by doing an API call in a build step through powershell. Could this work for you? Do a GET request to find the current release build counter and then update the appropriate parameter with a PUT request.

Comment: Seems to be the rest api is the only way to achieve the desired result. I've used something similar to psych's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23344586/3136110)